# Cant routing well in MVC3 ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm building my first MVC app, i'm using:

1) Visual Studio 2010 ultimate.
2) Mysql database
3) EntityFramework 4

And here is my code

Model:

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class region
    {
       public region()
      {
            this.provincia = new HashSet<provincia>();
        }

        public int REGION_ID { get; set; }
        public string REGION_NOMBRE { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<provincia> provincia { get; set; }
    }}
```

Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Region/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        region region = db.region.Find(id);
        return View(region);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Region/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(region region)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(region).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(region);
    }
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

This is the error when i'm trying to edit some row of Region.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type >'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in >'MvcApplication2.Controllers.RegionController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a >nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

When i call edit send me to /Region/Edit and it should be /Region/Edit/some_id

Thanks in advance

Comment: On your webpage, how is the link to the `edit` page formed?

Comment: Localhost/Region/Edit 
it should be ../Edit/1 for example.

Comment: Indeed, you need to use the `REGION_ID`. Can you show us the code (html/razor, cshtml) you use to create the link?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |

Comment: Of course, it's commented. It should be id=item.REGION_ID, now works perfect!! thank you Stefan.

Comment: `public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        region region = db.region.Find(id);
        return View(region);
    }`

you cannot pass an int type as parameter, as per your routing config.

Comment: @Stefan You should post it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to analyze the `cshtml` page where you construct the link.

It should include the id of the region like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.REGION_ID })
```